# How to customize shared information with Facebook Share methods

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

Im trying to share some content with the share dialog of facebook.
My target is to share a product that a costumer bought. I like to share a custom text, an image of the product and the product link.

It should look like that:

[image: MyImage]

I know that Facebook scrapes the URL I pass and gets it information based on the page, but I really wish that I can pass the text at least to the share dialog.

So the question is how to customize the informations that are being shared.

I tried different solutions, like using the sharer.php link and with the FB SDK with share_button that uses FB.ui.

Sharer.php

```
<div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100
    &p[url]=http://bit.ly/myelection&p[images][0]=http://election.gv.my/assets/vote.png
    &p[title]=My customized title
    &p[summary]=My customized summary"a-width="100">
</div>
```

Share-Button with JDK

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.gartenxxl.de/p-1473049000">
</div>
```

I did not try to use the Javascript SDK and the FB.Ui method to create a share-dialog, because I did not want to register as Facebook-Developer yet and create an App for the FB-Api-Key, but maybe thats the only way.
Then I would try that like this:

JS

```
$('#'#'#share_button').click(
    function(e){e.preventDefault();
         FB.ui(
         {
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'This is the content of the "name" field.',
            link: 'http://www.groupstudy.in/articlePost.php?id=A_111213073144',
            picture: 'http://www.groupstudy.in/img/logo3.jpeg',
            caption: 'Top 3 reasons why you should care about your finance',
            description: 'This is a Description',
            message: ''
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, dynamic content is not really possible anymore:

- The feed dialog is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
  Facebook will probably remove it sooner or later so i would not count
  on it.
- Even if it would be possible to add a custom message with a parameter, it would not be allowed. According to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), the message must be 100% user generated, prefilling is not allowed.
- All the existing (and NOT deprecated) possibilities only take the URL as parameter and they read the title/description/image from the Open Graph tags of that URL.

The best you can do for bought products is to use the sharer.php, the [Share Social Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) or the [FB.ui share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog). If you want a custom share button design, you would need to go with sharer.php or FB.ui share, of course.

Btw, this link may be helpful for the Open Graph tags: http://ogp.me/

Comment: That is really unforunately. So all I can do is sharing the product without any predefined text. Thanks for the info.

Comment: yeah, but you can use the Open Graph Tags of the product page (title/image/description). A lot easier to just add them to the html code.

Comment: i´ve added a very useful link for the open graph tags to my answer, check it out.